# Azure Kubernetes Service - Increase Windows disk space

Tags: azure, containers, azure-aks, diskspace, podspec

I'd like to host Windows containers, which act as build agents, at an Azure Kubernetes Service instance - unfortunately I can't increase the default 20GB pod disk space. I'd need more disk space for running build jobs at the pods.

The pod is getting deployed using an ADO pipeline by applying YAML which describes the workload.

Attaching the pod, and proving the disk space results in following:

```
PS: C:\ Get-PSDrive C

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
C                   0.31         19.57 FileSystem    C:\
```

Does anybody know how to increase the disk space?

At our on-premise cluster it is possible by adding

```
--storage-opt 50G
```

as parameter with regard to the modified Docker service parameter.

But how does it work for AKS?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: A parameter to what? The Docker Run command? How do you deploy the pod in AKS?

Comment: --> Modifying the docker service parameter and adding --storage-opt 
--> deployment with YAML, using ADO pipeline with a dedicated service connection

Comment: Edit your question, adding all the steps you just described in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

***We can increase the pod disk size in AKS by creating the disks manually using persistent volume***

*By default disk size will be 4GiB*
For me its 30GiB, I increased to 50GiB

[image]

**To increase the disk size please follow the below steps**

- I have created the storage class for disk

  ```
        vi sc.yaml
  ```

```yaml
   kind: StorageClass
   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azuredisk-premium-retain       
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk  
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters :
  storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS      
  kind: Managed
```

To deploy the Storage class use below command

```
         kubectl apply -f sc.yaml
```

Please use the below command to check the storage class created or not

```
      kubectl get sc
```

- I have created the persistent volume to to create the disk manually

  ```
      vi pvc.yaml
  ```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim   
metadata:
  name: azure-managed-disk-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: azuredisk-premium-retain
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50GiB
```

*In the pvc file i am increasing the storage to 50GiB*

To deploy the PVC use below commands

```
      kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml
      kubectl get pvc
```

- I have created the pod for mounting the volume

  ```
          vi pod.yaml
  ```

```yaml
kind: Pod     
apiVersion: v1
metadata:     
  name: newpod      #pod name
spec:
  containers:
 - name: newpod
    image: nginx:latest      
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"   # mounting the volume
      name: volume
  volumes:
 - name: volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:   
      claimName: azure-managed-disk-pvc
```

To deploy the pod

```
     kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
     kubectl get pods
```

- After deploying the pvc_file  Go-To>*portal*>*disks*>search with pvc_name you created, disk will be increased with created with **50GiB**
- Previously it was 30GiB now it increased to 50GiB

[image]

***NOTE*** : we cannot decrease the disk size once it increase

**Reference:**
[MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume)